# quickselect into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, quicksort

I have scoured the internet for all the various versions of quicksort implementation to translate into JavaScript and many of them do not successfully port.

I haven't been able to figure out if this is due to me not knowing a nuance about Java or C++, or the examples that people posted are broken.

I am not optimizing for performance, but how readable and logical it is to me.

I have arrived at this implementation, but I noticed that it does not work.

Outputs are random (likely due to the Math.random()), but as I follow the algo, I get frustrated with this following test case.

Outputs range from 999, 3, 100, 2, and 1000. I cannot follow the logic and would really appreciate someone explaining what's happening to give such erratic results.

```
function swap(array, idxA, idxB) {
    var temp = array[idxA] 
    array[idxA] = array[idxB]
    array[idxB] = temp
}

function partitionStart(arr, left, right, pivotIdx) {
  var storeIdx = left, pivotVal = arr[pivotIdx];  
  swap(arr, pivotIdx, right)
  for (var i = left; i <right; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < pivotVal) {
      swap(arr, storeIdx, i)
      storeIdx++
    }
  }
  swap(arr, pivotIdx, right);
  return storeIdx;
}

function quickSelectLoop(arr, k) {
  var pivotIndex, pivotNewIdx, pivotDist, 
  left = 0, right = arr.length-1 

  while(true) {
    pivotIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)
    pivotNewIdx = partitionStart(arr, left, right, pivotIndex)
    pivotDist = pivotNewIdx - left

    if (pivotDist === k) {
      return arr[pivotNewIdx-1]
    } else if (k < pivotDist) {
      right = pivotNewIdx -1
    } else {
      k -= pivotDist+1
      left = pivotNewIdx + 1
    }
  }  
}

var test2 = [1000,999,1,2,3,100,105]
console.log(quickSelectLoop(test2, 4))
```

expected output from quickSelect(test2, 4) => 100 since 100 is the 4th smallest element in the collection

Comment: What is your desired/expected output for that particular input?

Comment: The below console log should output 100, the 4th smallest element in the test2 array

Comment: And the `swap()` implementation that you don't show just swaps the values between two array indices?

Comment: yes. I found it to be very straightforward using a temp variable, but can add. check the top.

Comment: Please add your expected output to the question.

Comment: Edited as requested at the bottom!

Comment: Can I rewrite this code? I found a c# implementation that might work if I convert it to javascript http://snipd.net/quicksort-in-c still on my way to work

Comment: @AnthonyChung, have you read wiki on qsort? There is a great article regarding [how qsort works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Algorithm), and from your code it is obvious that you have no understanding what you do: your `quickSelectLoop` totally misses the point - you are making an assumption that array is already sorted, when you only partitioned it. Also you pass in '4' and expect 100, while using 0-based index. Yet, maybe I am missing something, but it looks totally incorrect.

Comment: No understanding is a bit harsh. I translated this code straight from someone's implementation. Wanted to find one that worked before trying to understand it. Will focus on switching those steps though thank you

Comment: was this translated directly from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current implementation has multiple flaws. I don't really understand what is the idea of your current code, so I'll try to explain how I understood your code, and then provide a corrected one.

`partitionStart` - partitions part of array from `left` to `right` indices using item at `pivotIdx` as parts separator. Returns index of separation `sepIdx`, such that every item before `sepIdx` is less than pivot item, and every item after it is greater or equal to it.

`quickSelectLoop` - selects k-th smallest item from the given array. 
Function relies on invariant that all items between `left` and `right`, while being in arbitrary order, are array's `left`..`right` smallest items, e.g.

if `left = 0`, `right = 2`, initial array = `{0,1,2,3,4}`, then
`arr = [A,B,C,x,x]`, where `{A,B,C} = {0,1,2}`, so `arr = [2,1,0,4,3]` and `arr = [0,1,2,3,4]` are both correct.

Corrected code with commentaries:

```
function partitionStart(arr, left, right) {  
  // You were passing pivotIdx here, I think that selecting pivotIdx 
  // should be this method's responsibility, so I moved the code here
  // Also you were taking pivotIdx ignoring left and right - fixed that
  var pivotIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (right - left + 1)) + left;
  var storeIdx = left, pivotVal = arr[pivotIdx]
  // You had a swap of pivot with the right here, 
  // which allowed you to traverse 1 item less in a cycle, 
  // but with the cost of one line of code - removed that
  for (var i = left; i <= right; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < pivotVal) {
      swap(arr, storeIdx, i)
      storeIdx++
    }
  }  
  // Here was a strange swap of pivot back from right to its position,
  // now it is not needed.
  return storeIdx;
}

function quickSelectLoop(arr, k) {  
  var pivotDist;   
  var left = 0, right = arr.length - 1;       
  while(right !== left) {
    // Maintaining: left <= k <= right, while enclosing left to right 
    pivotDist = partitionStart(arr, left, right)        
    // You were returning arr[k] here if pivotDist == k, 
    // but that is incorrect considering function's invariant - 
    // we can't make such a conclusion unless left == right.
    // I corrected that check - it is now located in the while loop.
    if (k < pivotDist) {
      right = pivotDist - 1;
    } else {
      // You were adding 1 here, which is incorrect, 
      // because item at pivotDist may be the answer as well.
      left = pivotDist;
    }
  }    

  // left == right, and we maintained 'left <= k <= right', so we have an answer
  return arr[k]
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8kxxxowq/8/)

Comment: Got it. So first core flaw was choosing a pivot element based on arr length and not dist between left and right pointers. Second was that I cannot assume items btwn left and right pointers contain the smallest items. (could be partitioning towards the other side.

With each iteration of while loop, left or right index should be moving closer inwards. Depending on comparison btwn pivotDist and k, left/right is reassigned

Comment: I saw two implementations of partition, this one swapped the pivot element with the end, partitioned the halves and tracked the starting point of the "larger half". upon completion, the partition switched it back. I did not manage state of my arr length or pivot at all in my interpretation.

Comment: thank you user3703125! I will study this and then try to implement it on my own without looking again.

Comment: @AnthonyChung, "Second was that I cannot assume items btwn left and right pointers contain the smallest items.", - no, I meant exactly the opposite: you can assume that sorted version of array will contain exactly the same items at indices between `left` and `right`, but exact positions of items within these boundaries may differ. In other words `quickSelectLoop` always guarantees you that any item in `arr` between `left` and `right` will have index between `left` and `right` in sorted version of `arr`.

Comment: @AnthonyChung, and using it we just moving `left` and `right` to `k` thus finding the exact item at index `k` in sorted array (which we can find when left==right==k), without sorting the whole array.

Comment: I completed this again on my own and also implemented a recursive version (basically used the while loop as a base case). Thank you again user3707125!

Comment: @user3707125 i thought that `partition` was meant to have the same invariant as in quicksort where after a run of the function, the pivot element is in its final position. this is why, i think, there was a need for a final swap.

Comment: This implementation causes an infinite loop, when some values occur multiple times in an input.

Comment: @IvanKuckir you can create a workaround for that case, like exit the loop if `partition` was called on the array of the same elements - https://jsfiddle.net/65kkboma/2/. However consider that this code is just a demonstration for the OP, I didn't make it to be reliable (i.e. you can find such `Math.random` function that will make it stuck in a loop)